# Como verificar se há erros na configuração do Apache antes de reiniciar?

Tags: linux, apache

Várias vezes que precisei reiniciar o Apache após fazer algumas configurações, tive o desgosto de receber uma mensagem de falha, por haver um erro na configuração.

Um colega aqui do site uma vez me informou que havia um comando no Apache que era possível checar a configuração. Assim, antes de reiniciar o servidor, eu poderia saber se cometi algum erro de sintaxe - mas pra variar, esqueci qual é o comando.

Qual é o comando usado para fazer isso?

Comment: Ta falando de verificar se o httpd está com problemas antes de iniciar o servidor?

Comment: @diegofm não, não, estou falando de um comando que verifica a sintaxe das configurações do Apache pra que, quando você for reiniciar, não tenha falhas. Existe esse comando, o Bacco me falou. Mas não lembro qual é :\

Answer (score 6):

```
apachectl configtest
```

ou

```
httpd -t
```

Comment: Cara, obrigado. Era esse mesmo. No meu caso usei `apache2ctl configtest`.